# Add hours with datetime.timedelta(hours=1)

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, timedelta

I saw in a related post that you cant add with .timedelta less than 24 hours but i need to really add a hour to my time, my code is this:

```
Hour =df['Hour'].values[0]
16:42:00
The column Hour is a datetime.time
```

And im trying to add one hour like this :

```
from datetime import date
HourPlus=datetime.datetime.combine(date.today() +datetime.timedelta(hours=1),Hour)
```

But only works if i add days=1 and not hours, how can i solve this ?

```
from datetime import date
HourPlus=datetime.datetime.combine(date.today() +datetime.timedelta(days=1),Hour)
2021-04-14 16:42:00
```

Comment: I dont want to change the dataframe...

Comment: HourPlus = df['Hour']+ pd.Timedelta("1 hours") ?

Comment: The column Hour is a  datetime.time so i cant add pandas.Timedelta

Comment: Edited, sorry!@MrFuppes

Comment: I added a answer with the problem solved, thanks anyways

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem, for some reason datetime.timedelta(hours=1) has to be out of the "(" like this :

```
a = datetime.datetime.combine(date.today(),Hour)
b = a + datetime.timedelta(hours=1)
```

And not like this

```
b=datetime.datetime.combine(date.today() +datetime.timedelta(hours=1),Hour)
```

Answer (score 0):

**pandas** `Timedelta()` works

```
df = pd.DataFrame(pd.date_range("1-apr-2021", freq="H", periods=12), columns=["hour"])

df.assign(plus1=df["hour"] + pd.Timedelta(hours=1))
```

#### output

```
                  hour               plus1
0  2021-04-01 00:00:00 2021-04-01 01:00:00
1  2021-04-01 01:00:00 2021-04-01 02:00:00
2  2021-04-01 02:00:00 2021-04-01 03:00:00
3  2021-04-01 03:00:00 2021-04-01 04:00:00
4  2021-04-01 04:00:00 2021-04-01 05:00:00
5  2021-04-01 05:00:00 2021-04-01 06:00:00
6  2021-04-01 06:00:00 2021-04-01 07:00:00
7  2021-04-01 07:00:00 2021-04-01 08:00:00
8  2021-04-01 08:00:00 2021-04-01 09:00:00
9  2021-04-01 09:00:00 2021-04-01 10:00:00
10 2021-04-01 10:00:00 2021-04-01 11:00:00
11 2021-04-01 11:00:00 2021-04-01 12:00:00
```

Comment: I dont want to change the dataframe, just store in a variable the value[0] and add 1 hour to it.

Comment: ok - given **pandas** tag,  thought you were looking to apply to all values.  `df["hour"].values[0] + pd.Timedelta(hours=1)` will do what you are looking for

Answer (score 0):

The heart of the problem in the question is that

`date.today() +datetime.timedelta(hours=1)`

fails to add an hour because datetime.date is a date not a datetime.  So, adding an hour to the date doesn't change the date.

You need to have a datetime.datetime object to meaningfully add an hour.

```
>>> import datetime 
>>> x = datetime.date.today()
>>> x
datetime.date(2021, 4, 13)
>>> x + datetime.timedelta(hours=1)
datetime.date(2021, 4, 13)
>>> y = datetime.datetime.today()
>>> y
datetime.datetime(2021, 4, 13, 14, 32, 41, 989496)
>>> y + datetime.timedelta(hours=1)
datetime.datetime(2021, 4, 13, 15, 32, 41, 989496)
>>>
```

Answer (score -1):

Using `datetime.now()` instead of `date.today()` keeps the time component.

```
import datetime as dt

nw = dt.datetime.now()
print(nw)
print(nw + dt.timedelta(hours=1))
```

Comment: Like i said, that is not working, only works if i change the hours for days